# How to create a thumbnail using the ffmpeg.exe

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to create a thumbnail of an .wmv video. I had tried the following code :

```
   Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
   string thumbpath, thumbname, videopath;
   string thumbargs, inputfile;                        
   thumbpath = "C:\\Users\\Tom\\Desktop\\picture gallery\\";
   thumbname = thumbpath + id.ToString() + ".jpg";
   videopath = "C:\\Users\\Tom\\Desktop\\video gallery\\";
   inputfile = Videopath + id.ToString() + ".wmv";   
   thumbargs = "-i " + inputfile + " -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:07 -s 150x150 -f image2 " +      thumbname;   
   Process thumbproc = new Process();
   thumbproc = new Process();
   thumbproc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\Tom\\Desktop\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe";
   thumbproc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   thumbproc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
   thumbproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
   try
   {
       thumbproc.Start();
       if (thumbproc != null)
       {
          thumbproc.Close();
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
       lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
       lblMessage.Visible = true;
   }
```

I am accessing the video which is stored in a folder "Video gallery". The problem with my solution is that it was showing the error "unable to find suitable output format for ffmpeg 'gallery\69b77a48-1b3c-4ce7-8c5a-fba10af5d9b1.jpg' " when I run the solution.

But if I remove the spaces in the path of thumbnail (picturegallery or videogallery) then it works fine.

Please tell me is there any problem with my "thumbargs" or anything i missing in my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
thumbproc.StartInfo.Arguments = thumbargs;
```

You forgot to initialize arguments.

Comment: I had added latter. thumbproc.StartInfo.Arguments = thumbargs;        then also i am facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this: [Convert Video to FLV and Create Thumbnails from file using C#](http://bickelsandhuconsulting.com/developer/asp-net/convert-video-to-flv-and-create-thumbnails-from-file-using-c/)

```
protected void Convert(string fileIn, string fileOut, string thumbOut)
{
try
{
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpegPath;

proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i " + fileIn +
" -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320×240 -aspect 4:3 -y " + fileOut.Split('.')[0] +
".flv";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Ref: 
[HOW-TO:Create video-preview thumbnails manually](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO%3aCreate_video-preview_thumbnails_manually)

**Command - Line**

```
ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i test.avi -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 test.jpg
```

> Check your code `Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();`, after generating new
>   GUID, is any file associated with new GUID.. first check that file
>   exists or not.